# Define Symfony 2 tag attribute as an array in XML configuration?

Tags: xml, symfony, configuration, symfony-2.1

```xml
<service id="my_service">
    <tag name="my_transport" supports="feature1, feature2, feature3" />
</service>
```

Would be possible to define `supports` attribute as `array` when dealing with XML configuration, instead of doing a `preg_split`?

Comment: maybe create multiple `<tag>` elements?

Comment: @WouterJ well I think that creating multiple tag with the same name will result in just one entry in the resulting array, as tag names are used as indexes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way do define attribute as `array`.

DependencyInjection loaders don't support this. (Ex. loading from `yml` throws exception `A "tags" attribute must be of a scalar-type (...)` if you try this)

[XmlFileLoader loading tags](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php#L182) uses [phpize](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/SimpleXMLElement.php#L102) parse attribute value as null, boolean, numeric or string.

Adding tag to service definition doesn't override previous added tag's definition, but adds new entry to array.

```
public function addTag($name, array $attributes = array())
{
    $this->tags[$name][] = $attributes;

    return $this;
}
```

So you should try create multiple `<tag>` elements (like  Wouter J said)

If your XML file will be like

```xml
<service id="my_service">
    <tag name="my_transport" supports="feature1" />
    <tag name="my_transport" supports="feature2" />
    <tag name="my_transport" supports="feature3" />
</service>
```

then $attributes for tag `my_transport` will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [supports] => feature1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [supports] => feature2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [supports] => feature3
        )

)
```

And sample usage

```php
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;

class MyCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition('my_transport_service');

        // Extensions must always be registered before everything else.
        // For instance, global variable definitions must be registered
        // afterward. If not, the globals from the extensions will never
        // be registered.
        $calls = $definition->getMethodCalls();
        $definition->setMethodCalls(array());
        foreach ($container->findTaggedServiceIds('my_transport') as $id => $attributes) {
            // print_r($attributes);
            foreach($attributes as $attrs)
            {
                switch($attrs['supports']){
                  case 'feature1':
                      $definition->addMethodCall('addTransportFeature1', array(new Reference($id)));
                      break;
                  case 'feature2':
                      $definition->addMethodCall('addTransportFeature2', array(new Reference($id)));
                      break;
                  case 'feature3':
                      $definition->addMethodCall('addTransportFeature3', array(new Reference($id)));
                      break;
                }
            }
        }
        $definition->setMethodCalls(array_merge($definition->getMethodCalls(), $calls));
    }
}
```

Comment: Good to know, I'll go for preg_split. I need to add a method call that accept an array. Thanks!